# How to enable rest cache in strapi?

Tags: rest, caching, strapi

Set up strapi-plugin-rest-cache with redis. Connection to the redis passes, debug shows that everything works. Entities appear in the redis. But requests are executed with the same time, both with cache and without cache.
What else can be seen?

```json
"rest-cache": {
    config: {
      provider: {
        name: "redis",
        options: {
          max: 32767,
          connection: "default",
        },
      },
      strategy: {
        enableEtag: true,
        debug: true,
        maxAge: 3600000,
        hitpass: false,
        keys: {
          useQueryParams: true,
        },
        contentTypes: [
          "api::homework.homework",
          "api::homework-task.homework-task",
          "api::homework-part.homework-part",
          "api::task.task",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
```

[image: Debug information from console]

[image: Another one]

I tried to change various parameters in the config, but it did not lead to anything.

After starting the server, the first request is executed in ~1sec. Further, if you send the second one right away, then it runs in 500ms. If you wait about 5 seconds and send the request again, then again it will be ~ 1sec. It does not depend on the cache, it works with and without the cache.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my steps to make **Redis** work in **Strapi 4**:

1. install packages: `strapi-plugin-redis`, `strapi-plugin-rest-cache`, `strapi-provider-rest-cache-redis`
2. Create Redis host and add it to `env`, or directly to a `config`. You can use `redislabs` for tests
3. Update `config` with new props (see below)
4. And you can build a project if it will not work (don't remember for sure did I build it for this plugin.)

**Config**:

```
{
  "redis": {
    "enabled": true,
    "config": {
      "connections": {
        "default": {
          "connection": {
            "host": "REDIS_HOST",
            "port": "REDIS_PORT",
            "password": "REDIS_PASS"
          },
          "settings": {
            "debug": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rest-cache": {
    "enabled": true,
    "config": {
      "provider": {
        "name": "redis",
        "getTimeout": 5000
      },
      "strategy": {
        "contentTypes": [
          {
            "contentType": "api::homework.homework",
            "hitpass": false
          }
        ],
        "debug": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```